# how to redirect from a page in a folder to the page in root directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a folder admin in my project. the main home is outside this folder. I want to redirect to the `mainhome.aspx` in the logout button click event of a page which is in the admin folder.

what I did is :

### Code

```
Response.Redirect("mainhome.aspx");
```

but it is not redirecting to the `mainhome.aspx` page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write it like this:

```
Response.Redirect("~/mainhome.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the root level, / now its looking for `mainhome.aspx` in your admin folder

`Response.Redirect("/mainhome.aspx");`